# Convert a tuple into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I've looked all over the internet and consulted a few books but I can't seem to find an example that illustrates what I am trying to do. I loathe to ask this on SO because it feels like a really basic question but I've been banging my head against the wall for the last few hours so here it goes:

How do i turn this:

```
   item = ((100,May),(160,June),(300,July),(140,August))
```

into this:

```
                {
                item:[
                    {
                        value:100,
                        label:'May'
                    },
                    {
                        value:160,
                        label:'June'
                    },
                    {
                        value:300,
                        label:'July'
                    },
                    {
                        value:140,
                        label:'August'
                    }
                ]
                }
```

Comment: You have a list of lists. You could walk the list using a list comprehension, and then each element would be one dictionary entry. Just pick it apart using [0] and [1] notation. This is very fundamental to Python. It would be worth your while to review what list comprehensions are and how they work. Also read through the iter module documentation.

Comment: What is the interest that the elements of the list are all dictionaries with the same keys `'value','label'` instead of directly tuples of the values ?? For me there is no interest: it only consists to add redundant information in the data structure, then when you'll have to make use of the data, you'll have to do additional treatment to obtain the values. If all the tuples were on the pattern (a value, a label), what would be the need to repeat this information in each element ? The value and label in one element won't spontaneously swap their positions !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{'item': [dict(value=value, label=label) for value, label in item]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> item = ((100,'May'),(160,'June'),(300,'July'),(140,'August'))
>>> keys = ('value','label')
>>> dd = {'item' : [dict(zip(keys,pair)) for pair in item]}
>>>
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dd)
{'item': [{'label': 'May', 'value': 100},
          {'label': 'June', 'value': 160},
          {'label': 'July', 'value': 300},
          {'label': 'August', 'value': 140}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(item=map(lambda x: dict(value=x[0],label=x[1]),item))
```